# Strange condition rendering failed in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a this component that set a variable to the background image, this won't work

```
render() {

    const target_role_gravatar = this.props.target_role_gravatar

    return(
         <div className="logo" 
            style={{"backgroundImage": "url(" + target_role_gravatar ? target_role_gravatar : 'something else' + ")"}}>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I got all value of target_role_gravatar.

But this worked.

```
render() {

        const target_role_gravatar = this.props.target_role_gravatar

        return(
            <div>
                {target_role_gravatar && <div className="logo" 
                    style={{"backgroundImage": "url(" + target_role_gravatar + ")"}}>
                </div>}

                {!target_role_gravatar && <div className="logo" 
                    style={{"backgroundImage": "url(" + this.logo + ")"}}>
                </div>}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` has a higher precedence than `?:`. Your expression is evaluated as

```
(prefix + condition) ? yes : (no + suffix)
```

Solution: Use parenthesis to change the precedence:

```
"url(" + (target_role_gravatar ? target_role_gravatar : 'something else') + ")"
```

Or use template literals:

```
`url(${target_role_gravatar ? target_role_gravatar : 'something else'})`
```

Comment: oh ya I missed the `(` `)`